# MudAutocomplete not displaying default value in Edit mode

Tags: autocomplete, mudblazor

I have an Mudautocompete component that i use to add and edit a mudtable using a dialog. I got all the code working except when i use the dialog for edit mode it does not display the value of the current selection.

I would like the mudautocompelte to prepopulate the form with the selected city (see example) and if the user choose, they can change the city name.

Thanks
Francois

Please see example at https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYQSYRkAneoApIKB.

Comment: You should probably work again on your code. There are multiple errors when assigning values. Eg. in the class CityViewModelItems you have 'id = Id' instead of 'Id=id'.
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkQouRYqnsqsIGjY I have updated your UpdateAsync method aswell as the 'public CityViewModelItems(int id, string? title)' constructor. Does it now, what you want it to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.